# How to turn multiple lists from one variable into one list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Edit: I realize the question is confusing now, so I will try to clarify. For the code I am using I don't know what the lists that are being outputted are. All I know is that (using the example) when I print(j), it turns out like the output I have put below. I hope that clears up any confusion.

I am creating a program that will use OCR to read documents then output text. The problem is for the program to work I need the text output to be a list. How can I convert it to a list?

This is not the specific code but an example.

```py
l = ['3']
m = ['2']
n = ['1']
for j in (l,m,n):
        print(j)
```

In this example I can't change j or anything before j.

The output:

```py
['3']
['2']
['1']
```

The real code has b = list but I can't change any of the code before b.

I want it to look like this:

```py
['3', '2', '1']
```

Comment: Hey You can look at my answer for other possible ways for concatenating as well.

Comment: There are many options and some of them are present in answers. Was just curious why there is only one element in all of the `list`? I would opt of variables rather.

Answer (score 1):

When you did `(l,m,n)` that made a tuple object. You can append lists using the `+` operator.

```py
l = ['3']
m = ['2']
n = ['1']
j = l + m + n
print(j)
```

output:

```
['3', '2', '1']
```

Answer (score 0):

list concatenation works with the addition sign:

```
new_list = l + m + n
```